# Segmentation fault when modifying a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault error in this code, but don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr = "Linux";
    *ptr = 'T';

    printf("\n [%s] \n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ptr` is a pointer that points to a string literal, but you can't modify a string literal, change it to:

```
char ptr[] = "Linux";
```

Answer (score 0):

The fault is

```
*ptr = 'T';
```

It should be a char array,not a string.